# Nav tab li border-bottom issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a nav tabs in bootstrap4 with animation left to right in border bottom it's working good when I'm click on the other words
But I faced an issue when I'm click on border-bottom on any other words it's not changing items of tab pane
Any Solution for this issue ?

Full Code : [link](https://codepen.io/enespro/pen/KKgxNBG)

```js
function activaTab(tab) {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};

activaTab('aaa');

const items = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-tabs li");
items.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector("li.active").classList.remove("active");
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">Main Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">Education & Certification</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">
      <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-left:20px; padding-top: 3px; ">User experience design - UI/UX</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">
      <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-left:20px; padding-top: 3px;">Front End Designer - RGD Group</p>
      <p style="font-size: 16px; margin-left:20px;">2020 - Current</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">
      <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-left:20px; padding-top: 3px; ">Diploma in Civil Enginnering - Florida University</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `a` should be inside the `li`. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? I was not providing a solution just pointing our a fundamental issue with your HTML.

Comment: Time for a break Dude. You are mixing everything up. I just fixed your snippet. You pasted your HTML in the CSS frame of the snippet editor... And the JS in the HTML frame. -- Take a walk and/or a sleep.

Comment: Thank you for editing , The reason of making mistake that i tired to share all my code but they refused it cuz because my code was long so I got confused of that ..

Comment: This is the full code [link](https://codepen.io/enespro/pen/KKgxNBG)                               The problem when I click on below of any other word its not showing tab contents